# setEGLConfigChooser crashes app when i set stencil size > 0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

this is the current code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

public class OpenglstencilActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GLSurfaceView view = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    view.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 4);
    view.setRenderer(new OpenGLRenderer());
    setContentView(view);

}
}
```

and i updated the manifest to include

if i change the stencilsize from 4 to 0 then the app will load. any value other than 0 and i get an illegal argument exception. i need the stencil size set as im trying to use the stencil buffer.

any ideas?

Comment: Bear in mind that setting setEGLConfigChooser(..) will try to choose configuration that matches RGBA depth exactly and depth/stencil buffers are at least of requested depth. So it's possible there isn't a configuration which meets all these criteria while there can be one which has stencil buffer but lesser RGBA depth.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Android emulator, none of the EGL configurations are suitable to enable stencil.

So no luck for using stencil on the emulator.

If you are using a device, then it is a different matter and this answer would be wrong.

Comment: i was using emulator, now im using a galaxy tablet and none of my configurations are allowing the app to run. I'm going to spend the rest of the day trying to return some kind of list with all possible configurations, I'm sure its possible...?

Comment: im getting 2 configs, 1 allows a stencil buffer but no alpha (5,6,5,0,24,8) and the other causes the app to crash on load (8,8,8,8,24,8).